# Hint on solving an integral $\int \tan^\frac{2}{n} x dx $

Tags: calculus

I try to solve the following integral

$\int\tan^{\frac{2}{n}} x dx$,

where $n\in N$ and $n> 2$.

For solving I use the following change of variables
$z = \tan x$
and then the integral is written as
$\int \frac{z^{\frac{2}{n}}}{1 + z^2} dz $.

Now I do not know what to do next.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you think it has a nice analytic formula?

Comment: @Andrei I do not know.  I just guessed

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+tan%28x%29%5E%282%2Fn%29+dx) gives a "nice" answer in terms of the hypergeometric function,
$$
\int \tan^{2/n}(x)\,dx = \frac{n \tan^{(n+2)/n}(x) {}_2F_1(1, \frac 12 + \frac 1n; \frac 32 + \frac 1n; -\tan^2(x))}{n+2} + C
$$